# Why can't I seem to find the error in my program when compiling. Help needed

Tags: java, compiler-errors

The pet store program should start with the user being able to choose to adopt a pet or give a pet the to the shop. If the user wants to adopt a pet, they should be able to see either all available pets, unless they say they know what type of pet they want, then show only available pets of that type.

The 4 methods that will need to be created for this program should:

add new pets
get a pet adopted
show pets by type
show pets available for adoption
Object Class: Pets.java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Pets {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        private double age; // age of the animal (e.g. for 6 months the age would be .5)
        private String petName; // name of the animal
        private String aType; // the type of the pet (e.g. "bird", "dog", "cat", "fish", etc)
        private int collarID; // id number for the pets
        private boolean isAdopted = false; // truth of if the pet has been adopted or not
        private String newOwner;
        private Date adoptionDate;

        public double getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(double age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String getPetName() {
            return petName; 
        }

        public void setPetName(String petName) {
            this.petName = petName;
        }

        public String getaType() {
            return aType;
        }

        public void setaType(String aType) {
            this.aType = aType;
        }

        public int getCollarId() {
            return collarID;
        }

        public void setCollarId(int collarId) {
            this.collarID = collarId;
        }

        public boolean isAdoptated() {
            return isAdopted;
        }

        public void setAdoptated(boolean isAdoptated) {
            this.isAdopted = isAdoptated;
        }

        public Date getAdoptionDate() {
            return adoptionDate;
        }

        public void setAdoptionDate(Date adoptionDate) {
            this.adoptionDate = adoptionDate;
        }

        @Override

        public String toString() {
            return "Pets [age=" + age + ", petName=" + petName + ", aType=" + aType + ", collarId=" + collarID

            + ", isAdoptated=" + isAdopted + ", adoptionDate=" + adoptionDate + "]";

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define the data fields and methods inside the class, but not inside the main()-method. The main()-method is the entry point of your java application and could be used to create an instance of your Pets class.
e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pets pet = new Pets();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is not compiling for 2 main reasons:

- You are specifying access modifiers on variables inside a method (in this case **main**), which is forbidden;
- You are writing methods (*e.g.* **getAge**) inside another method (**main**) and trying to return a variable (*e.g.* **age**) that is out of that scope, in fact the variable age is not known inside the getAge method, because it's declared in the main method.

You should move the variable declaration to class level, and then have all methods separated using those variables. I'll give you a sketch, not the complete solution:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Pets {
    /* Insert all variable declarations here */
    private double age;

    /* Constructor if you need it */
    public Pets(/* parameters you think you need */) {
        // Set attributes when you declare a new Pets()
    }

    /* Insert all methods you need here */
    public double getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }
```

The positioning of the main method - for what I've understoon from your description - should be placed outside this class, in another class where the whole application will start to run. The Pet class should serve only for anything concerning pets (the four methods you will need to implement and all getters/setters for retrieving private class variables).

Answer (score 0):

You’ve happened to put about everything — private fields and public methods — inside you main method. That doesn’t make sense. Everything that is in your `main`, move it outside, right under the line `public class Pets {`. That should fix your compiler error.